# Multivariable calculus - I need to prove that these derivatives are different, but how?

Tags: calculus

$f(x, y) \begin{cases} \frac{2xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} \space(x, y)\space\neq(0, 0) \\0    \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases} $

I need to prove that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}(0, 0) \neq \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y \partial  x}(0,0)$

But I don't know from where I should start.

Comment: Here's a LaTeX tip: instead of using `\delta` for your partial derivatives, try using `\partial`

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited my post.

Comment: Have you tried computing the partial derivatives by the product and quotient rules?

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but since it's asking the partial derivatives at (0, 0), and the function's value at (0, 0) is 0, wouldn't that make every partial derivative at the origin 0?

Comment: Not necessarily: $f(x) = x$ have value 0 at the origin, but its first derivative is of course 1

Comment: I deleted my previous message by mistake, sorry. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @bounceback That is wrong.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,h)-f(x,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2x(x^2-h^2)}{x^2+h^2}=2x$. Then take derivative with respect to $x$ and evaluate at $x=0$ to get that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)=2$. Similarly, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(0,y)=-2y$.

Comment: Thanks, you're quite right, it's been some time since I've computed one of these. I'll delete the erroneous comment.

Comment: Why is $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = 2$? Since the derivative of $-2y$ is $-2$, shouldn't it be $-2$ instead of $2$?